# no suitable image found. Did find in xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7.2

I am able to run app in simulator but when i am trying to run app in devoce getting this error at time of launch

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ActionSheetPicker_3_0.framework/ActionSheetPicker_3_0
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C3A53A7E-DD32-472D-B7DE-F71DC032F6F5/Stylo.app/Stylo
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C3A53A7E-DD32-472D-B7DE-
F71DC032F6F5/Stylo.app/Frameworks/ActionSheetPicker_3_0.framework/ActionSheetPicker_3_0: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C3A53A7E-DD32-472D-B7DE-F71DC032F6F5/Stylo.app/Frameworks/ActionSheetPicker_3_0.framework/ActionSheetPicker_3_0'
```

Comment: Whatever this Action Sheet Picker framework is, it's the problem.

Comment: are you sure _ActionSheetPicker_3_0_ is being linked against device architecture?

Comment: how to check ActionSheetPicker_3_0 linked or not in device architecture because its working in simulator

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me quite recently after I updated the iOS on my phone. I didn't see an updated listed for Xcode, but when I searched on the web I found there was a newer beta version. Updating to that beta version fixed the issue for me.

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/